# Encode file to base64 and send it to servlet

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

for my project i need to get a file from  html form, encode it to base64 format with javascript, make it json format and send it to a servlet. If someone can help me i will be thankful.
Here's where i am, but it's not working:

```
var data;
var file = document.getElementById('fileId').files[0];
function getBase64(file) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(file);
       reader.onload = function () {
           data = reader.result;
         console.log(reader.result);
       };
       reader.onerror = function (error) {
         console.log('Error: ', error);
       };
    }

$.ajax({
    url: 'post',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log("success");
    },
});
```

Comment: Just did but now nothing happens.

Comment: why do you set `dataType` to `json` in ajax call? Your filecontent can not be a `json` after encoding

Comment: console.log gives undefined